# The Run button in VS Code don't show up [Python]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently create an app using Python in VS Code. I made some modifications and now the Run button in the top left is gone. I can only run the app with the debug mode. I already try to click the little bug as it was suggested on another post. It is doing the same on my macbook when I share my code with Github. If I run the same code in a new file the Run button came back.

[image: see the image as an exemple.]

Do you have any way to solve this problem without having to create a new file?

Comment: Which extension are you using?

Comment: Only the basic Python extension.

Comment: What happens if you add a `.py` file extension to your file name?

Answer (score 11):

You have to **right click** on the three dots icon next to where the run button should be, and select the `Reset Menu` option.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options here:

- **Install Microsoft Python extension for Visual Studio Code** and **Microsoft Jupyter extension for Visual Studio Code**

Search for Python in Microsoft Visual Studio Code's Extension: Marketplace and hit on install.

[image]

Search for Jupyter in Microsoft Visual Studio Code's Extension: Marketplace and hit on install.

[image]

Or you can use your terminal or command prompt to install them. Open the terminal or command prompt and write these commands there.

Install Microsoft Python extension,

```
code --install-extension ms-python.python
```

Install Microsoft Jupyter extension ,

```
code --install-extension ms-toolsai.jupyter
```

- **Install Code Runner for Visual Studio Code**

Search for Code Runner in Microsoft Visual Studio Code's Extension: Marketplace and hit on install.

[image]

Or you can use your terminal or command prompt to install it. Open the terminal and write the command.

Install Code Runner,

```
code --install-extension formulahendry.code-runner
```

You must go with the first option by Microsoft. If you go with both the options, you install **Code Runner** and **Microsoft Python** and **Jupyter** extensions then the **Microsoft Python** extension will only work if you disable **Code Runner**.

**Code Runner** is a good extension for **C, C++, Java, Javascript, Perl, ...** but for **Python** **Microsoft Python and Jupyter** extension is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the "Code Runner" extension, with that you should be able to run your programmes inside VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar kind of issue and what I did was "uninstall python" and then install it again.
it worked perfectly in my case.
I guess all MS products are plagued with these restarting/re-installing issues.

[image: Marketplace python extension for VSCode by Microsoft]

Comment: Yes. Also if you open your code in a container, you may have to install your extensions again, including that one, as if it were a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to extensions then type python
The first result must be python developed by Microsoft
Install it/Enable it or reload it and the button will show [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaFbr.png)

[Python Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaFbr.png)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't put any extension to your file.
Think it should be *.py :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall python extension in Vscode
if that is also not working then right click on 3dots and reset the menu (see *image below*):

[image: image description]