# VS Code- "Run" button not appearing for my Jupyter Notebook, even after installing extensions and setting kernel

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

TL;DR: how can I run my Jupyter notbook in VS Code, given I've tried the [previously-suggested solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559273/the-run-button-in-vs-code-dont-show-up-python) (like installing certain extensions) and nothing appears to be working?

---

I've got the following blank .ipynb file:

[image: 'Hello world' Jupyter notebook]

I've installed both Microsoft's Jupyter and Python extensions installed:

[image: relevant installed extensions]

I created the file in screenshot #1 above via the command palette to `Jupyter > Create New Blank Notebook`.  We see a cell which I've changed from plain text to Python.  I don't see a "Run" button in my editor like I do in [the VS Code + Jupyter docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks).  I hit Shift-Enter to run the cell, but instead of the expected output, I'm prompted to "Select a kernel for Untitled-1.ipynb`:

[image: prompt to select a kernel]

I try to type in my best guess for which kernel they're referring to (I use Python 3.9.5 in my terminal), but typing things like `3.9.5` and `Python`, thinking I might see an auto-complete helper or a dropdown with valid options to choose from, but this didn't happen.

The "Restart" and "Interrupt" buttons are greyed-out and disabled, implying that the Jupyter server isn't running.  However, [the docs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-support-for-native-editing-of-jupyter-notebooks-in-vs-code/) imply that I should be able to just create a new Jupyter notebook and start running code immediately:

> Here’s how to get started with Jupyter in VS Code.
>
> - If you don’t already have an existing Jupyter Notebook file, open the
>   VS Code Command Palette with the shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + P (Windows)
>   or Command + SHIFT + P (macOS), and run the “Python: Create Blank New
>   Jupyter Notebook” command.
> - If you already have a Jupyter Notebook
>   file, it’s as simple as just opening that file in VS Code. It will
>   automatically open with the new native Jupyter editor.
>
> Once you have a Jupyter Notebook open, you can add new cells, write code in cells, run cells, and perform other notebook actions.

I saw the following `Jupyter Server: local` component at the bottom of my screen.  I see the icon on the left-hand side shows a *disconnected* power cord; not sure if that implies the server itself is disconnected.  At any rate, I tried clicking on this component to see what would happen:

[image]

I see the default behavior is already selected, which leads me to believe that VS Code would automatically start up a Jupyter server when the app itself is launched.

[image]

I also tried setting the kernel via the command palette (`Jupyter > Select interpreter to start Jupyter server`), and this time I *did* see my version of Python.  However, selecting that option didn't seem to resolve the issue, since I still don't see a "Run" button:

[image: selecting Python interpreter via command palette]

I tried looking in all the tabs at the bottom of the screen (`Terminal`, `Jupyter Variables`, `Debug Console`, `Problems`, and `Output`), but didn't see anything at all.

Interestingly, when I run `Jupyter > Create Interactive Window` from the command palette, I *am* able to create Jupyter cells and run Python code in them.  However, I consider this to be a workaround and not a solution to my primary problem of being unable to run both interactive sessions *and* notebooks:

[image]

These are all my VS Code settings:

```
{
    "ruby.intellisense": "rubyLocate",
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#dd7aab"
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "[yaml]": {
    "breadcrumbs.showEvents": true,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.autoIndent": "advanced"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
    "notebook.lineNumbers": "on",
    "jupyter.variableQueries": [
    
    ],
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Extension
2. Search "Jupyter" from Microsoft
3. Click "Switch to Pre-Release Version"
4. Click "Reload"

[VS Code Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8eGa.jpg)

Comment: run button reappears after I reload the extension

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer,

1.Just refresh your IDE and then restart your IDE .
2.INSTALL KERNEL ON YOUR IDE.

Sometimes extensions in IDE must not have hosted therefore the extensions does not work.In this case just restart your IDE and then host your extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you're still searching for an answer.
What worked for me was to install [conda](https://conda.io/) ([anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) or [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) will do).
Then in the command prompt, type:

```
conda install ipykernel
```

Restart your IDE and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and solved it by:

```
pip install ipython
```

After installing this package and Jupyter extensions in Visual Studio code, the run button is available left of the cell and you can click it to run the cell.

Then it tries to connect to the kernel and for the first time asks you to install Ipykernel if it doesn't show this message, etc you can run this code in Command Prompt:

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
```

also for more information, you can see this page:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/index.html